# Binding variables in SQLAlchemy v2

Tags: sqlalchemy

Upgraded SQL Alchemy to 2.x.x versions,
Bind variables of the following form are no longer supported:

```
query = “SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COL_NAME_1 = (%s) and COL_NAME_2 = (%s)“, bind_variable=[1, 2]
```

( Since the new versions expect dictionaries or tuples)

The following is still supported:

```py
query = “SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COL_NAME =:x”, bind_variable={“x”: “123”}
```

(so 123 will replace the :x in the query).

Is there a built-in way in SQL Alchemy to implement this replacement in an elegant way? I thought of creating a dictionary by myself which replaces each place with a key and then assigns it to a value, but it sounds a bit problematic to me.

Comment: There's no built-in solution, you need to do the refactoring yourself.